# Variable in a variable dict name in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have dictionary like so:

```
mydatabases:
  group1:
    db_name: group1_database
  group2:
    db_name: group2_database
```

I want to be able to pass in *a_group* variable at runtime to retrieve the *db_name*. So something like this

```
{{ mydatabases.{{ a_group }}.db_name }}
```

but I know this method is not possible.

Something like the below of course works and I can get the value which will return group1_database but not exactly what I want.

```
- debug: 
    msg:"{{ mydatabases.group1.db_name }}"
```

This give me an undefined variable

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['mydatabases' + a_group + 'db_name'] }}"
```

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pythonic way to access variables:

The `test.yml` playbook. Note the quotes in the `debug` task.

```
- name: Print var
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    mydatabases:
      group1:
        db_name: group1_database
      group2:
        db_name: group2_database

    required_db: group2


  tasks:
  - name: Print a var
    debug:
      msg: "{{ mydatabases[required_db]['db_name'] }}"
```

An example run:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i localhost, playbooks/tests/test.yml

PLAY [Print var] ****************************************************

TASK [Print a var] *************************************************************
Wednesday 21 April 2021  15:23:21 +0200 (0:00:00.023)       0:00:00.023 ******* 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "group2_database"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

Playbook run took 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds
Wednesday 21 April 2021  15:23:21 +0200 (0:00:00.047)       0:00:00.070 ******* 
=============================================================================== 
Print a var ------------------------------------------------------------- 0.05s
```

Comment: As you can mix the dots/object and bracket/array notations at will when possible, `"{{ mydatabases[required_db].db_name }}"` is also an alternative.